# python dataframe related questions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For the below dataframe,

```
date1         date2        userid
2020-10-20  2020-10-22     101
2020-09-10  2020-10-11     101
2020-10-20  2020-10-23     101
2020-12-05  2020-12-06     102
2020-12-04  2020-12-06     102
```

Can I get the output like this

```
   date1            date2       userid
 2020-10-20     2020-10-22       101
 2020-09-10     2020-10-11       101
 2020-12-05     2020-12-06       102
```

The relationship from date1 and date2 should be 1:1 and vice-versa.

Comment: No actually the relationship should be unique from both columns date1 and date2

Answer (score 0):

you can groupby each columns and take first item:

```
data_string = io.StringIO('''date1         date2        userid
2020-10-20  2020-10-22     101
2020-09-10  2020-10-11     101
2020-10-20  2020-10-23     101
2020-12-05  2020-12-06     102
2020-12-04  2020-12-06     102''')
df = pd.read_csv(data_string,sep=r'\s+')
df = df.groupby(['date2'],as_index=False).first()
df = df.groupby(['date1'],as_index=False).first()

df
>>>
    date1   date2   userid
0   2020-09-10  2020-10-11  101
1   2020-10-20  2020-10-22  101
2   2020-12-05  2020-12-06  102
```

note that this dataframe ended up sorted